# radio button validation not working asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I have three input filed (text - tow radio button) for one property asp-validation-for works only for the input text I want to validate radio button also if it is not checked ,Model :

```
        [BindProperty,Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
         public string PriceAfter { get; set; }
```

Index.cshtml :

```
                         <div class="form-group">                    
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" 
                                       asp-for="Ad.PriceAfter">
                                <label class="custom-control custom-radio mb-2 ml-4">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" 
                                            value="new" asp-for="Ad.PriceAfter"  id="PriceAfter">
                                    <span class="custom-control-label"><a href="#" class="text-muted">new</a></span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-radio  mb-2">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" 
                                           value="Used" asp-for="Ad.PriceAfter" id="PriceAfter">
                                    <span class="custom-control-label">
                                        <a href="#" class="text-muted">Used </a></span>

                                </label>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Ad.PriceAfter" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
```

[image: Design]

Comment: A little confused. There are three input fileds for one property, the validation will just work for the first input field of Ad.PriceAfter. Once it has a value, the server side model will pass validation and not validate the rest input fields for same property. Can you tell us your design intent

Comment: I update the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can define another field in your class. One is for the input text field and the other is for radio button.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Ad Ad { get; set; }
}

public class Ad
{
    [BindProperty, Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string PriceAfter { get; set; }

    [BindProperty, Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control "
               asp-for="Ad.PriceAfter">
        <span asp-validation-for="Ad.PriceAfter" class="text-danger"></span>
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio mb-2 ">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input"
                   value="new" asp-for="Ad.Status" id="PriceAfter">
            <span class="custom-control-label"><a href="#" class="text-muted">new</a></span>
        </label>
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio  mb-2">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input"
                   value="Used" asp-for="Ad.Status" id="PriceAfter">
            <span class="custom-control-label">
                <a href="#" class="text-muted">Used </a>
            </span>

        </label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Ad.Status" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(myViewModel);
        }

        return Content("Ok");
    }
```

Result:

[image]